# How do I use socket.io over SSL? (What SSL certificates do I need to get?)

Tags: node.js, ssl, websocket, socket.io

I've got a nodejs application that's served from heroku, on one domain (with SSL), and connects to a nodejs application on another domain (not served on heroku) via websockets with socket.io.   The websocket connection would initially not work because the websocket server was just under http://   I created a self-signed certificate, to have the server serve under https, but it seems that the self-signed certificate doesn't work with chrome, and I need to use purchase a certificate signed by a third party.

The question is, What I need to purchase exactly for a certificate?

The websocket server is under app.domain.com, and the client is served from app.herokuapp.com

do I have to get a certificate for domain.com ?   for *.domain.com?   or is this not even a certificate problem with socket.io and possibly something else?

Thanks

Comment: Should check out https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint if you haven't already, also you don't need a (usually more expensive) wildcard (*) cert if youre not making use of it.

Comment: What is implied but not specifically mentioned in that heroku ssl-endpoint article is that you need to buy both an ssl certificate and a domain name. Certificate authorities are not supposed to issue ssl certs to people who don't own the domain and since you don't own herokuapp.com then you can't buy an ssl certificate for it or any of its subdomains.

Comment: Secretly, there are some CA that do sell certificates to non-owners like that French CA that sold google.com certs to their intelligence/government agencies - if and when a CA gets caught doing this all browser vendors from Apple to Google to Microsoft will ban that CA as soon as possible making all certificates issued by that CA invalid.

Answer (score 0):

To get app.domain.com on SSL, you do need to buy a certificate for that:

Check: http://www.rapidssl.com/
For free ones (not very different your self signed certificate), see http://www.startssl.com/  I can't remember off the top if Chrome will let you run it, but it will definitely not show you the green sign.

And then finally for app.herokuapp.com I am assuming you already know that comes pre-enabled with SSL (http://app.herokuapp.com) in case you need that.

Cheers

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.  Do I need a domain.com certificate? or a *.domain.com certificate? Or both? that's what I don't really know..   thanks!